# Would a house built in 1745 have a water tank in the attic? (up to 1847)

Tags: 19th-century, 18th-century, architecture, engineering

Was looking at the floorplans on [this page](https://www.colliers.com/en-ie/properties/the-sopwell-estate-ballingarry/irl-the-sopwell-estate-ballingarry-tipperary-e53-yn99/irl58000339) (picture 43), was wondering if buildings from 1745-1847 were likely to have water tanks in the attic? Would this have been added during a relatively modern (say 100 years) refit? My impression would be that during the initial period, the attic 'floor' was used to house domestics and provide insulation / rain cover, rather than provide water storage / pressure infrastructure.

Have done some Googling on this with no success, but honestly I don't have much experience/knowledge of this topic!

Comment: What better way to obtain water for an occasional bath than collecting rainwater from such a large roof? It's not like Tipperary has the hot summers or cold winters of North America that mandate heavy attic insulation. It was more usual in the *Old World* for the upstairs to be the family quarters with servants in the damp cold sub-ground floor.

Comment: When you say "tank", I think of something made of metal or plastic.  You might have more luck searching for "cistern".  Rainwater-collecting cisterns were used in some places in that period, but I don't know how common they'd be in your area.

Comment: My understanding is that indoor plumbing wasn't really a thing until the 1800s... @jamesqf I'm not seeing much evidence for cisterns in rural Ireland during this period, but again, not an expert...!

Comment: How would they pump the water? There is no steam power and no electricity as yet.

Comment: @Jos Why would they need a pump when gravity will do just fine? The tank is in the attic.

Comment: @CareyGregory how does the water get there? Magic?

Comment: You can always pretender to be an interested potential purchaser of the property & contact the agent for more details about the tank, particularly its history. Is it a modern tank & is it still being used? When was it last replaced? Are there protective measures to protect against leakage or rupture of the tank? If it's not being used then why is it there?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Rain collecting tanks usually are at ground level so they may collect rain from a bigger surface. Anyway the main problem with a water tank in the attic is that water is very heavy and it would require lots of reinforcement (and for a house built in 1745 it would still be a significant risk).

Comment: @SJuan76: No - cisterns collecting rainwater are usually near (the height of) the roof they are collecting runoff from so there is no need to pump the water back up again. Jos: Cisterns generally collect rainwater off the roof, specifically to obviate pumping. Further, by 1750 the Dutch had been running windmill pumps for land drainage for roughly 500 years.

Comment: @Jos: Ever spent much time in Ireland?  If so, you will have noticed that it rains quite a lot there.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens thats not always so, in most of london's grand houses and even more modest middle class ones, servants lived upstairs in the attics.  The evidence is in the smaller fireplaces given to servants quarters, and the much smaller windows